# How to bulk download pages in confluence as individual pdf?

Tags: python, scripting, confluence

I'm trying to download pages from my confluence as individual pdf files.
I have more than 50 child pages and I want to download each page as individual pdf.
For example if I have:

```
 Parent of Parent   
      Parent Page
       Child Page 1
       Child Page 2
       Child page 3
```

I want to download the child page 1, 2 and 3 as seperate pdf.

Is there anyway or any script to do this?
Maybe python?
Please help me out guys

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `atlassian-python-api==3.27.0`.

To get page id [instruction](https://confluence.som.yale.edu/display/SC/Finding+the+Page+ID+of+a+Confluence+Page)

If you want to download simply children from the parent side:

```
from atlassian import Confluence

PARENT_PAGE_ID = 'parent page id'

# This creates connection object confluence with your credentials
confluence = Confluence(
    url='https://confluence.xxxxx.com/',
    username='your_username',
    password='your_password'
)

# Get object contains pages information
children = confluence.get_child_pages(PARENT_PAGE_ID)
for i in children:
    title = i['title']
    id = i['id']
    pdf_name = title + '.pdf'
    # Get confluence page as byte-stream
    content = confluence.get_page_as_pdf(id)
    file_pdf = open(pdf_name, 'wb')
    file_pdf.write(content)
    file_pdf.close()
```

If you want to download all the children and their children you have to use recursion:

```
def tree_downloader(confluence: Confluence, children: list) -> list:
    list_id = []
    for i in children:
        if isinstance(i, str):
            i_id = i
        else:
            i_id = i['id']
        grandchildren = confluence.get_child_pages(i_id)
        list_id.append(i_id)
        if grandchildren:
            list_id.extend(tree_downloader(confluence, grandchildren))
    return list_id
```

EDIT: here a version of what your function could look like:

```
children = confluence.get_child_pages(PARENT_PAGE_ID)
children = tree_downloader(confluence, children)
for i in children:
    p = confluence.get_page_by_id(i)
    title = p['title']
    id = p['id']
    pdf_name = title+'.pdf'
    content = confluence.get_page_as_pdf(id)
    file_pdf = open(pdf_name, 'wb')
    file_pdf.write(content)
    file_pdf.close()
```